# How to access ag-Grid API in React function component (useState hook)?

Tags: function, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

What is the best way of accessing ag-Grid [API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/) inside of **React function** component?

I have to use some of the methods from API (`getSelectedNodes`, `setColumnDefs` etc.) so I save a reference to the API (using `useState` hook) in `onGridReady` event handler:

```
onGridReady={params => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
}}
```

and then I can call the API like this: `gridApi.getSelectedNodes()`

I haven't noticed any problems with this approach, but I'm wondering if there's more *idiomatic* way?

Stack:

- ag-grid-community & ag-grid-react 22.1.1
- react 16.12.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I am doing it in my project. You can use `useRef` hook to store `gridApi`.

```
const gridApi = useRef();

const onGridReady = params => {

   gridApi.current = params.api;  // <== this is how you save it

   const datasource = getServerDataSource(
     gridApi.current,
     {
       size: AppConstants.PAGE_SIZE,
       url: baseUrl,
       defaultFilter: props.defaultFilter
     }
   );

  gridApi.current.setServerSideDatasource(datasource); // <== this is how you use it
};
```

Comment: This seems like viable option too! I wish somebody from ag-Grid team observed ag-grid tag on SE and provide authoritative answer... :/

Comment: @user1068352 yeah me too. I also have couple of questions for functional component agGrid on my SE account. I request you kindly upvote and accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I will try to reach ag team to get an official recommendation. If it matches with useRef I'll definitely accept your answer. Remember to upvote a question ;)

Answer (score 14):

We find the most idiomatic way to use a ref. As the api is not a state of our component. It is actually possible to simply do:

```
<AgGridReact ref={grid}/>
```

and then use it with

```
grid.current.api
```

**Here an example:**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'
import { AgGridReact as AgGridReactType } from 'ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact'

const ShopList = () => {
  const grid = useRef<AgGridReactType>(null)

 ...

  return (
    <AgGridReact ref={grid} columnDefs={columnDefs} rowData={shops} />
  )

}
```

The good thing here is, that you will have access to the gridApi but als to to the columnApi. Simply like this:

```
// rendering menu to show/hide columns:
{columnDefs.map(columnDef =>
  <>
    <input
    type='checkbox'
    checked={
        grid.current
        ? grid.current.columnApi.getColumn(columnDef.field).isVisible()
        : !(columnDef as { hide: boolean }).hide
    }
    onChange={() => {
        if (grid.current?.api) {
        const col = grid.current.columnApi.getColumn(columnDef.field)
        grid.current.columnApi.setColumnVisible(columnDef.field, !col.isVisible())
        grid.current.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
        setForceUpdate(x => ++x)
        }
    }}
    />
    <span>{columnDef.headerName}</span>
  </>
)}
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. Best in line with the official docs.

Comment: As a suggestion, you may want to add `// prettier-ignore` above the `const grid = useRef<AgGridReactType>(null)` line to prevent prettier auto-formatting it in VS Code.

Comment: Great answer. It gives typescript users a type they can use instead of `any`. But just wondering, why this strange import `import { AgGridReact as AgGridReactType } from 'ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact'`? Could you please point me to the official doc where this is used/stated. I would have expected this to be a "top-level" module like inside going deep into the `lib` of another module.

Comment: I can't tell you for sure right now, but I think the type was either not exposed top-level or there was type with the same name exposed that had a slightly wrong typing.

Comment: you will actually need ```import type { AgGridReact as AgGridReactType } from 'ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact';```
In modern ts 4.X

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same issue but here is a workaround that at least can get you the selected rows. Essentially what I'm doing is sending the api from the agGrid callbacks to another function. Specifically I use OnSelectionChanged callback to grab the current row node. Example below:

```
  const onSelectionChanged = params => {
    setDetails(params.api.getSelectedRows());
  };

return (<AgGridReact
          columnDefs={agData.columnDefs}
          rowSelection={'single'}
          enableCellTextSelection={true}
          defaultColDef={{
            resizable: true,
          }}
          rowHeight={50}
          rowData={agData.rowData}
          onCellFocused={function(params) {
            if (params.rowIndex != null) {
              let nNode = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(params.rowIndex);
              nNode.setSelected(true, true);
            }
          }}
          onSelectionChanged={function(params) {
            onSelectionChanged(params);
            params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
          }}
          onGridReady={function(params) {
            let gridApi = params.api;
            gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
          }}
          deltaRowDataMode={true}
          getRowNodeId={function(data) {
            return data.id;
          }}
        />);
```

Comment: I would like to have persistent access to the API though - I even tried hooking the api to the component state but it seems to lose scope of the original grid instance...it seems to create new instances that are not associated with the initial grid API.. FYI I am using React Boilerplate with Redux, Sagas, Reselect, etc.

Comment: Have you tried useState hook? It works for me just fine.